# Automatic Email Notifications

Tags: asp.net, email, web-services, notifications

I wrote an asp.net program that is designed to retrieve user data. The process, in which the user can log in to the system and input his data, has a Start Date and an End Date where the user is not allowed to log in before the start date or after the end date.

I want to send an email notification to the users to log in to the system and input their data. This email notification has to be sent on the Start Date of the process (which is stored in an a database table). Additionally, two reminder emails must be sent to the users of the system. The time of sending the email reminder will be calculated automatically by generating two dates between the Start Date and End Date of the process.

The problem I am facing at the moment is how to send the email notification automatically. I wrote the procedure for sending the email notification and I stored it in an asp.net web service. But how can I trigger this procedure on Start Date and on each Reminder Date?

I tried several methods and thought of using timers but to no avail.

Appreciate your help,
shaknon

Answer (score 1):

you can create another project to trigger and call web service and use Windows Service to control the timer.

this old tutorial is suitable for your case : [Timer Objects in Windows Services with C#.NET](http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/C-Sharp/Timer-Objects-in-Windows-Services-with-C-sharp-dot-NET/)

Answer (score 0):

You either need to write a scheduler application for doing this automatically or write an aspx page from where user can trigger email sending or you can setup job in SQL Server also.

Even if you can write stand alone application for sending emails you can use windows scheduler also.